# Intern JS + saucelabs : Does not start session when using firefox browser

Tags: javascript, firefox, intern, ui-testing, saucelabs

I've started using Intern js with saucelabs for ui testing recently. Want to test in all browsers so obviously firefox is not excluded.

Here is my gruntfile config:

```
        runner: {
            options: {
                config: 'tests/intern',
                runType: 'runner',
                sauceAccessKey: '<my key>',
                sauceUsername: '<my username>',
                environments: [
                   /* {
                        name: 'chrome',
                        browserName: 'chrome',
                        version: [ '52.0' ],
                        platform: [ 'Windows 7', 'OS X 10.10' ]
                    },*/
                    {
                        browserName: 'firefox',
                        platform: ['Windows 8', 'OS X 10.9'],
                        marionette: true 
                    },
                    /*{
                        browserName: 'internet explorer',
                        version: [ '11.0' ],
                        platform: ['Windows 7']
                    }*/
                ]
            }
        }
```

Here is intern.js:

```
define({

    capabilities: {
        'selenium-version': '2.46.0'
    },

    maxConcurrency: 3,

    tunnel: 'SauceLabsTunnel',
    tunnelOptions: {
        drivers: ['chrome', 'firefox']
    },

    useSauceConnect: false,

    // Configuration options for the module loader; any AMD configuration options supported by the Dojo loader can be
    // used here

    // Non-functional test suite(s) to run in each browser
    suites: [  ],

    // Functional test suite(s) to run in each browser once non-functional tests are completed
    functionalSuites: [ 'tests/first' ],

    // A regular expression matching URLs to files that should not be included in code coverage analysis
    excludeInstrumentation: /^/
});
```

Tests with chrome and IE (Actually IE8 also have some problem !!) are working fine. When running using grunt intern what actually happens is:

```
Listening on 0.0.0.0:9000                                                                                                                                                                                 
Tunnel started                                                                                                                                                                                            
‣ Created session chrome 40 on Windows 7 (8773c63bf5a4469e8d92db57e6f51b63)                                                                                                                               
✓ chrome 40 on Windows 7 - index - toppage (2.969s)                                                                                                                                                       
No unit test coverage for chrome 40 on Windows 7                                                                                                                                                          
>> chrome 40 on Windows 7: 0/1 tests failed                                                                                                                                                               

‣ Created session chrome 46 on OS X 10.10 (b2ffbb9a639d4515a51b758ae382a1cf)                                                                                                                              
✓ chrome 46 on OS X 10.10 - index - toppage (3.514s)                                                                                                                                                      
No unit test coverage for chrome 46 on OS X 10.10                                                                                                                                                         
>> chrome 46 on OS X 10.10: 0/1 tests failed 
>> TOTAL: tested 2 platforms, 0/2 tests failed                                                                                                                                                            
Goodbye.                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Done.
```

But when I try to use firefox (I tried with older version too), then output is like this:

```
Listening on 0.0.0.0:9000                                                                                                                                                                                 
Tunnel started
```

So it seems that intern or something is not able to start session with firefox.
When I see in my saucelabs dashboard and try to see live video, what I'm seeing is in firefox nothing happens, except there is mozilla.org/ ... in address bar and web page is saying that "Secure connection cannot be established". After some time browser will be restarted. and this happens for several times.

Tunnel keeps running and nothing happens.

Someone please guide me , is there any misconfiguration ? or inadequate config ?

Thanking in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue may be with the configuration of your environments. I am using the following and tests are working as expected on Sauce Labs.

```
environments: [
    { browserName: 'chrome', version: '51.0', platform: 'Windows 7' },
    { browserName: 'internet explorer', version: '11.0', platform: 'Windows 7' },
    { browserName: 'firefox', version: '45.0', platform: 'Windows 8.1' },
    { browserName: 'firefox', version: '46.0', platform: 'Windows 10' }
],
```

Also, I have seen that specifying a 'selenium-version' previous to 2.50 has caused errors as well. I would recommend moving to the following:

```
capabilities: {
    'selenium-version': '2.53.0',
},
```

Comment: thanks for you answer. It works fine. I didn't know about latest selenium version !! Anyway, the problem still with IE8. intern.js try to execute some scripts on address bar of browser before executing our test cases. But in ie8 it doesn't work and so our test cases never get executed. I also tried to set fixSessionCapabilities:false for ie8 but it doesn't work. Do you have any idea?